# From UnixNano() to Time{}

Tags: go, sqlite

I want to convert a [UnixNano() int64](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.UnixNano) time stamp back to a [time.Time{}](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time).

Taking a step back, here is the larger issue.

We have a database with timestamps, we use these timestamps to pull entries. In nanotime there should never be duplicate timestamps. The database is an embedded SQLite3 database (via the "[github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3)" driver) with the stamp held in an INTEGER column. We do some sorting and filtering with the number value, in the form of clauses on selects and within a few views.

Thus when we bind our integers to our prepared statements like:

```
INSERT INTO "event" ("timestamp", "command", "data") VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

we bind time.Now().UnixNano().

However when I try to convert the item to a data structure, I find I cannot accurately take a UnixNano time and reconstitute it back to a time.Time{} structure.

They never match.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
t1 := time.Now()
fmt.Println(t1, t1.UnixNano())
t2 := time.Unix(0, t1.UnixNano())
fmt.Println(t2, t2.UnixNano())
```

gives you

```
2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC 1257894000000000000
2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC 1257894000000000000
```

http://play.golang.org/p/Q68IaR9zPK

BTW, are you sure that the integer value saved to the database is not truncated (e.g. can store int64)?

Comment: Well, that made me feel stupid, i guess i figured that because it also needed t.sec, it was only permitted to be a value between 0 and .999 secs.

Comment: Reasonably sure, though ill do some more testing, to verify.

Comment: I get nanoseconds (Go 1.21 on Ubuntu 22.04): `2024-01-22 21:35:53.496373044 +0100 CET m=+0.000013188 1705955753496373044

2024-01-22 21:35:53.496373044 +0100 CET 1705955753496373044`

Answer (score 0):

```
func main() {
    t1 := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(t1, t1.UnixNano())
    ns := t1.UnixNano()
    t2 := time.Unix(0, ns)  // <------- parse the int64 created by t.UnixNano()
    fmt.Println(t2, t2.UnixNano())
}
```

I guess time.UnixNano() to parse the int64 created by t.UnixNano() does not exist, because [time.Unix(sec int64, nsec int64) Time](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Unix) exists.

Result with Go 1.21 on Ubuntu 22.04:

```
2024-01-22 21:43:30.52613572 +0100 CET m=+0.000014357 1705956210526135720
2024-01-22 21:43:30.52613572 +0100 CET 1705956210526135720
```